# vertex index correspondence between two meshes

Tags: 3d, vertical-alignment, mesh, wavefront, face

I have two wavefront obj of human face. One is a generic human-face and other is a mesh created from a 2D picture. I want to map the generated human-face mesh onto the generic mesh. The problem is that they have different vertex indices.

generic humanface:

f 4 2 1
f 8 6 5
f 13 15 14
f 17 19 18
f 32 30 29
f 36 34 33
f 37 39 38
f 21 23 20
f 25 27 24
f 41 43 42
f 48 46 45
f 52 50 49
f 53 55 54
f 60 58 57
f 29 62 61
f 66 64 63
f 67 6 68
f 72 70 69
f 76 74 73
f 77 79 78
...

generated:
f 1 2 131
f 1 131 130
f 2 3 131
f 3 132 131
f 3 4 133
f 3 133 132
f 4 5 133
f 5 134 133
f 5 6 135
f 5 135 134
....

Is it possible to achieve vertex index correspondence between two different meshes in python?

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54645430/how-is-a-3d-morph-implemented-in-computer-graphics

Comment: Also check this paper: https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/files/421/SC-99-33.pdf that is somewhat old but easy to understand and not too hard for implementing in your case (a face is a single patch).